# How to create pie chart using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I have a table which shows my data and it works perfectly. I need to add in a pie chart also to show the exact same data that was shown on the table.

```
 <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account Type</th>
                    <th>Account Number</th>
                    <th>Account Balance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $acc_type = $row ['account_type'];
                    $acc_num = $row ['account_number'];  
                    $acc_bal = $row ['account_balance']; 

                    ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $acc_type ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $acc_num ?></td>
                        <td>$ <?php echo $acc_bal ?></td>
                    <?php
                }
                ?> 
                    </tr>
            </tbody>  
            <tr class="alt">
                <?php 
                $query = "SELECT SUM(account_balance) AS account_total FROM account WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $acc_total = $row ['account_total'];
                ?>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><b>Total: </b></td>
                <td align="right"><b>$ <?php echo $acc_total ?> </b></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Have you googled for "php pie chart library" ?

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes but I do not understand :(

Comment: if you do not understand the documentation of a 3rd party chart library, it's a bad idea to start doing it yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Use a 3rd party.

Here is one. Look at their Example #15 - Basic Pie graphs
http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple15

Comment: Doesnt really help but I have a rough idea on how to start now! Thank you so much have a good day :D

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try the Google graphs, that is the easiest way.

Check out the link 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution I really just went to this site
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts
and echo the whole code and it works.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer to the question. Link-only answers are discouraged here because they may become out of date if the linked site changes. Please put the gist of the linked information here to maintain relevancy over time.